# I have built a react-native app. I am restricting this app in Dubai region

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am building a react native app. The app is restricted usage in Dubai.

The app can be restricted usage in certain countries by changing the settings in app store and google play console for ios and android respectively. In case, the user downloads the app in Singapore and then moves to Dubai. Will he still be able to access the app? If yes, How can I prevent this?

The user should not be able to access the app if he downloads the app in a certain country and then moves to a restricted country.

Comment: Fetch his location and show a popup to restrict the usage.

Answer (score 1):

```
Install & import axios from npm
```

Initialize your component state with country name & country code

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        countryName: '',
        countryCode: ''
    }
}
```

Add this function to your component

```
getGeoInfo = () => {
    axios.get('https://ipapi.co/json/').then((response) => {
        let data = response.data;
        this.setState({
            countryName: data.country_name,
            countryCode: data.country_calling_code
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

And call this.getGeoInfo() to set country name & country code to your state. I called that from componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.getGeoInfo();
}
```

Check country Dubai and block it here

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is via the backend of your app. I will tell you how we did it in our app. Every time the app launches, we used to do an authentication call to our backend to get the info on the user status. We also send the current IP of the user in that call. The backend then reads that IP and checks that the IP belongs to the region where the app is allowed to operate. If it does not, then the authentication call simply sends, response with status code 4xx or something like that, which is then handled in the app and we show an appropriate message to the user.

If you dont have a backend, you can check this in your app also. Just get the IP and write a logic to find out the region.